# iOS: Audio not coming with Twilio ReplayKitExample in Broadcast

Tags: ios, twilio, broadcast, screensharing, replaykit

We are currently using the Twilio ReplayKitExample for broadcast in conjunction with video calls using the library found at https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios. While we are able to successfully conduct video calls without any issues, we have encountered a problem with the audio of the user on the other end not being audible when screen sharing (broadcasting). We have tried several potential solutions, but none have worked thus far.

We have looked into several resources, including the following links:

- https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/issues/519
- https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/issues/601
- https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/issues?q=broadcast+audio

We have also opened a question on the issue at https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-ios/issues/658.

We would be extremely grateful for any assistance you can provide. Thank you in advance for your help!